# Django equivalent of SQL REPLACE

Tags: django, django-orm

Is there a Django ORM best practice for this SQL:

```
REPLACE app_model SET field_1 = 'some val', field_2 = 'some val';
```

Assumption: field_1 or field_2 would have a unique key on them (or in my case on both), otherwise this would always evaluate to an INSERT.

Edit:

My best personal answer right now is this, but it's 2-3 queries where 1 should be possible:

```
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    try:
        Model(field_1='some val',field_2='some val').validate_unique()
        Model(field_1='some val',field_2='some val',extra_field='some val').save()
    except ValidationError:
        Model.objects.filter(field_1='some val',field_2='some val').update(extra_field='some val')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You say you want `REPLACE`, which I believe is supposed to *delete* any existing rows before inserting, but your example indicates you want something more like [`UPSERT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert).

AFAIK, django doesn't support `REPLACE` (or sqlite's `INSERT OR REPLACE`, or `UPSERT`).  But your code could be consolidated:

```
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(field_1='some val', field_2='some_val')
obj.extra_field = 'some_val'
obj.save()
```

This of course assumes that either `field_1`, `field_2`, or both are unique (as you've said).

It's still two queries (a `SELECT` for `get_or_create`, and an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` for `save`), but until an `UPSERT`-like solution comes along (and it may not for a long, long time), it may be the best you can do.

Comment: if you want to update a lot of fields, that method would give ugly code, but I can't think of anything better (more compact)

Answer (score 11):

Since Django 1.7 you can use [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'profession': 'musician'},
)
```

Comment: that will throw an `IntegrityError` if one of the attributes is defined as `unique=True`

Answer (score 5):

I think the following is more efficient.

```
(obj, created) = Model.objects.get_or_create(
   field_1 = 'some val',
   field_2 = 'some_val',
   defaults = {
      'extra_field': 'some_val'
   },
)
if not created and obj.extra_field != 'some_val':
   obj.extra_field = 'some_val'
   obj.save(
      update_fields = [
         'extra_field',
      ],
   )
```

This will only update the extra_field if the row was not created and needs to be updated.

Comment: this is the better answer... Django had the `defaults` arg since at least 1.3 (oldest docs I can still find online). BTW you don't need the brackets around `(obj, created)` :)

Comment: @Anentropic yeah I know I have pretty bad code OCD and for some reason I liked that better, but in the past year I have adopted most of the PEP8 formatting standards, in a way PEP8 is enabling/feeding my code OCD even more now!

Comment: I know, same happened to me :)